# ArrayList x,y coordinate distance calculation

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this calculation work? I keep working myself in circles and I honestly don't know what to do. This is my current file that I'm working on:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment_12 {

   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

      System.out.println("name goes here");
      System.out.println("You may quit at any time by typing \"Q\".");
      ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
      ArrayList<Double> numbers2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
      System.out.println("Please enter an X coordinate: ");
      //Point pnt = new Point();

      while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
         numbers.add(input.nextDouble());
         System.out.println("Please enter a Y coordinate: ");
         numbers2.add(input.nextDouble());

         double x = (double) numbers.get(0);
         double y = (double) numbers2.get(0);

         Point pnt = new Point(x, y);
         System.out.println(pnt.getX()); // just to make sure the "object created"?
         System.out.println(pnt.getY()); // same as before, I think
         System.out.println(pnt.distance(pnt.getX(), pnt.getY())); // how to calculate??
      }

      if (input.equals("Q")){
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

And this is the class that I'm just trying to figure out how to make the actual actual calculation work:

```
public class Point {

   private double x;
   private double y;

   public Point(){
      this.x = 0.0;
      this.y = 0.0;
   }

   public Point(double x,double y){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }

   public double distance(Point pt){
      return Math.sqrt((x - pt.x)*(x - pt.x) + (y - pt.y)*(y - pt.y));
   }

   public double getX(){
      return x;
   }

   public double getY(){
      return y;
   }
}
```

I'm truly struggling on what exactly to do. I seemingly created the `pnt` object with `x` and `y`, but I don't necessarily understand how to make the calculated distance be available to print. I have tried `System.out.println(pnt.distance(pnt.getX(), pnt.getY()));` and other similar things, but I'm just stumped. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need _two_ points, so you can invoke `point1.distance(point2)`

Comment: *FYI:* `input.equals("Q")` will **never** be true.

Comment: What is the purpose of the lists if you only ever get the first element (`get(0)`)?

Comment: @Andreas I think your advice is not useful at SpaceGrapes current level of programming knowledge..

Comment: @LonelyNeuron My comments are intended to make OP *think* about it. How is that not useful? People learn much more from a solution they fix themselves, rather than being spoon-fed an answer.

Comment: @Andreas If OP has no idea about how to pass parameters to a method, I am pretty sure that OP has no idea of either `List`s or generics in general. I didn't mean to offend you, I just wanted to point out that not all advise is useful to all users, as they may struggle with much more basics concepts. Pointing out more advanced problems might be more confusing in the end

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Neither of my comments are for "more advanced problems", since they are both problems that needs to be fixed for that program to work ok, i.e. they are problems that OP is having right now. If OP is "advanced" enough the try using an `ArrayList`, OP is advanced enough to figure out that repeated adding a value to a list, but only ever retrieving the first element, is not the right path to a working solution. Besides, there were just *comments*, not answers.

Comment: @Andreas with "more advanced problems" I meant more advanced that OP, not more advanced compared to most programmers. Also both of the things you pointed out are terrible code, but it does work - for the most part. Also I am pretty sure the `ArrayList` in there is part of some code provided in some instruction.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thank you! That really opened my eyes actually.

Comment: @SpaceGrape You're welcome.  Objects are not easy to get the hang of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a careful look at the signature of your method:

```
double distance(Point pt)
//              ⬑ single parameter of type Point
```

This method is called on a `Point`, which you did correctly with `point.distance(...`. But it takes **one** parameter, which also is of type `Point`. You didn't pass a `Point` though. Let me rephrase your code a little:

```
double someX = pnt.getX();
double someY = pnt.getY();
pnt.distance(someX, someY)
```

This can't work, as you pass **two `double`**, instead of **one `Point`**. So what you *can* do is:

```
pnt.distance(pnt)
//           ⬑ single parameter of type Point
```

Compare this to what you did:

```
pnt.distance(pnt.getX(), pnt.getY())
//           ⬑          ⬑ two parameters of type double
```

But let me point out that this will return `0`, as you just calculated a `Point`s distance to itself. Try:

```
Point otherPnt = new Point(13, 8.5);
System.out.println(pnt.distance(otherPnt));
```

Which will return at least a somewhat more interesting result.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! It really did help, so I appreciate it. :)